# lemma involving homogeneous ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals

I am studying Klaus Hulek's algebraic geometry book.
In lemma 2.13 b) is said 
"If I is homogeneous, then I is prime iff for any pair of homogeneous elements $f,g\in S$ we have: $fg \in I \Leftrightarrow f \in I $ or $g \in I$.
Proving this lemma is left to the reader, but there is anything to prove on this statement? I mean, doesn't this follow by definition of prime ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, $I$ being a prime ideal requires that for any pair of (not necessarily homogeneous) elements $f, g\in S$ we have: $fg \in I \Rightarrow f\in I$ or $g\in I$. (The other direction will always be true by definition of an ideal)

In other words it remains to prove that you can reduce the condition of being prime to the case where both $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous elements.

Comment: oh, got it, thank u very much